# is it possible to make a div width auto BUT now more than x pixels/inches? in CSS

Tags: css, html

I was just wondering if it's possible to give a div a width of auto (expandable) but also not allow it to expand more then x amount of pixels?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/max-width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you can use the style, max-width

```
div {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max-width`:

http://jsfiddle.net/CssJJ/

Be aware that certain version of IE don't support this (would have to look up which) and some I believe require a strict doctype.

Answer (score 1):

```
max-width: %/px/em/vh/vw,etc...
```

Also if you put `max-width: 100%` on an image element, the image scales to fit its parent container. Ie. Responsive images